# jboss maven project add jar not exist in public repository

Tags: maven, jboss

I need to add a jar not exist in publi repo to my maven project i have using system scope like this :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${user.home}/jars/my.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

This solution working fine in local machine but not in distant server. when i google it i find that system scope is aleardy a bad practice so there is another solution to add a jar to project?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

**First**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

**Second**:

Install this jar in your local repository and it will be included in your built project.
You can add jar in you local repository like this:

```
    mvn install:install-file
   -Dfile=<path-to-file>
   -DgroupId=<group-id>
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
   -Dversion=<version>
   -Dpackaging=<packaging>
   -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file>  the path to the file to load
   <group-id>      the group that the file should be registered under
   <artifact-id>   the artifact name for the file
   <version>       the version of the file
   <packaging>     the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

**Edit your pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>X.Y.Z</version>
</dependency>
```